# jmeter script to login from google plus or facebook

Tags: jmeter

jmeter works fine if we have login & password on a same screen & no redirect url

But

When we tried to test the url,which have redirect url's (ex login using Google plus or facebook)
it is very difficult to test in jmeter,

take example of any site when uses login with google plus or login with Facebook account

if we try to login through Google+ then suppose if any redirect authentication service in exists between home page & login screen 
then, while getting the response, not getting the response of snap deal logged in page instead of that am getting the response of authentication service

So can you pls let me know how to skip the response of authentication service  & get the response of logged in screen

Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) world.

In order to be able to bypass OAuth protection you'll need a token. There are 2 ways to get it:

1. Capture from real browser by any developer tools extension
2. Go all the OAuth challenge, the best way is using OAuth Java client libraries

   - [google-oauth-java-client](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client)
   - [How to Implement Facebook App Authorization in Java](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-implement-facebook-oauth-2.0-app-authorization-process-in-java/)

   from [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) guide for a little bit more detailed description.